# Archipack autohole not working with Archipack walls?

Tags: archipack-add-on

As per title: I'm placing a door in a wall, and the hole is not being generated.
I've read there should be a "autohole" option, but I can't find it anywhere.
Blender 2.91.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The door hasn't been created the right way.
There is a panel CREATE under the ARCHIPACK tab on the TOOL panel. One must create doors and windows using that tab, not by adding an Archipack mesh as a mesh.

[image]